# How can we run another thread B for some time when thread A gets crash in MacOS?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, exception, objective-c++

In MacOS, with Objective-c/C++.

I want to know if we can run thread B for some time when thread A gets crash in MacOS.

Because thread B(flushs log from buffer) some important info which are good for troubleshooting, if we can flush the log buffer out in thread B, it would be great.

As I know, we can use following codes to handle the SIGTERM:
signal(SIGTERM, processSignal);

But it couldn't achieve my goal.

Are there some other technologies to achieve my above goal.

Comment: Try use a [signal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal). Read it carefully since it has many limitation.

Comment: There are ways to do this by using Mach messaging - you can configure a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) to cause a Mach message to be sent to another thread. I don't remember off the top of my head how it works, but you should be able to find something with a web search.